# How to retrieve and display a login id after successful login

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-8

I have a problem in retrieving the exact user login Id after the login has been successful, and to display it on a status text-box in my admin frame

```
public String i;
public  String getId()
{
    return this.i;
}   
private void btnLogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String sql ="select * from ad where logId=? and password=?";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,loginTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(2,passTxt.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password is correct"); i = rs.getString("logId");
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            AdminTable s = new AdminTable();
            s.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password incorrect");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

//This is my second frame, the admin frame. i want the login Id to appear on a textbox automatically after the user has logged in 
  `Login lo = new Login();
    public Admin() {
        initComponents();
       jTextAdId.setText(lo.i);
    }`

Comment: What isn't working? You have the login ID in `loginTxt.getText()`, what more do you need?

Comment: i want the login ID to be displayed on my admin frame as a status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the id to show on AdminTable you have to pass it, something like:

```
  AdminTable s = new AdminTable(loginTxt.getText());
```

For better help post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).